# angular-google-maps not working other than index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using ionic+cordova i tried every thing but I did'nt find a solution and there is no error in console.
If I put my Geolocation.html tags in index.html it is working fine but after routing/state change its not working.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ionic/css/ionic.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ionic/css/ionicons.min.css"></link>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">

        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-filter.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/lodash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/constants.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/services.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>

<body >
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

module config:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ionic', 'angular.filter', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ngCordova']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider, uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        v: '3.17',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization',
        language: 'en',
        sensor: 'false',
      });

    $stateProvider.state('routeGeoLocation', {
    url: '/routeGeoLocation',
    templateUrl:'pages/GeoLocation.html',
  })
});
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller("GeoLocationController", function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, uiGmapIsReady){
    $scope.map = {center: {latitude: 60.1451, longitude: -99.6680 }, zoom: 8 };
    $scope.readyForMap = true;
    $scope.control = {};

    uiGmapIsReady.promise().then(function (maps) {
        $scope.map = {center: {latitude: 60.1451, longitude: -99.6680 }, zoom: 8 };
//        $scope.control.refresh();
    });
```

GeoLocation.html

```
<ion-content class="has-header" ng-controller='GeoLocationController'>
<div id="map_canvas">
 <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options"></ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

If any body suggest where i am doing wrong it will be help full.
Thanks.

Comment: could you create a fiddle?